# PHP уникализатор контента

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование

разбираюсь с пхп. написал программу для замены символов на похожие.
как избавиться от второй текстэрии и выводить обработанный текст обратно в верхнюю?

```html
<form action="" method="post">
<textarea rows="10" cols="100" name="Word"></textarea>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit"value="Convert">
<input type="submit" name="empty" value="Erase">
</form>
<p>

<?php

if($_POST['submit'])
{$Word=$_POST['Word'];
 $Word =strtolower($Word);
 $SymbWord = str_split($Word);
 $i=0;
 
 while ($i<strlen($Word))
 { 
   switch($SymbWord[$i])
   { case  a : $RezWord=$RezWord. "а";break;
  case  b : $RezWord=$RezWord. "β";break;
  case  c : $RezWord=$RezWord. "с";break;
  case  d : $RezWord=$RezWord. "ɗ";break;
  case  e : $RezWord=$RezWord. "е";break;
  case  f : $RezWord=$RezWord. "Ғ";break;
  case  g : $RezWord=$RezWord. "ɠ ";break;
  case  h : $RezWord=$RezWord. "ħ";break;
  case  i : $RezWord=$RezWord. "î";break;
  case  j : $RezWord=$RezWord. "ʝ";break;
  case  k : $RezWord=$RezWord. "к";break;
  case  l : $RezWord=$RezWord. "ɭ";break;
  case  m : $RezWord=$RezWord. "ɱ";break;
  case  n : $RezWord=$RezWord. "ŋ";break;
  case  o : $RezWord=$RezWord. "о";break;
  case  p : $RezWord=$RezWord. "р";break;
  case  q : $RezWord=$RezWord. "q";break;
  case  r : $RezWord=$RezWord. "ɾ";break;
  case  s : $RezWord=$RezWord. "ʂ";break;
  case  t : $RezWord=$RezWord. "ʈ";break;
  case  u : $RezWord=$RezWord. "ʋ";break;
  case  v : $RezWord=$RezWord. "ⱱ";break;
  case  w : $RezWord=$RezWord. "ω";break;
  case  x : $RezWord=$RezWord. "х";break;
  case  y : $RezWord=$RezWord. "у";break;
  case  z : $RezWord=$RezWord. "ʐ";break;
  case  " "  : $RezWord=$RezWord. " ";break;
  case  "."  : $RezWord=$RezWord. ".";break;
  case  ","  : $RezWord=$RezWord. ",";break;
  case  "?"  : $RezWord=$RezWord. "?";break;
  case  "!"  : $RezWord=$RezWord. "!";break;
  default : echo"*";break;
    }
  $i++;
 }
}

if($_POST['empty'])
{$Word=$_POST['Word'];
echo" ";
}
?>
<p/>

<textarea rows="10" cols="100"name="R" >
<?PHP
echo $RezWord;
?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: Вообще конечно лучше отделить вывод результата от скриптов которые обрабатывают данные

Comment: и почему бы не воспользоваться [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) с двумя входящими массивами и строкой, а то такой switch пугает :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

if($_POST['submit'])
{$Word=$_POST['Word'];
    $Word =strtolower($Word);
    $SymbWord = str_split($Word);
    $i=0;

    while ($i<strlen($Word))
    {   
      switch($SymbWord[$i])
      { case  a : $RezWord=$RezWord. "а";break;
        case  b : $RezWord=$RezWord. "β";break;
        case  c : $RezWord=$RezWord. "с";break;
        case  d : $RezWord=$RezWord. "ɗ";break;
        case  e : $RezWord=$RezWord. "е";break;
        case  f : $RezWord=$RezWord. "Ғ";break;
        case  g : $RezWord=$RezWord. "ɠ ";break;
        case  h : $RezWord=$RezWord. "ħ";break;
        case  i : $RezWord=$RezWord. "î";break;
        case  j : $RezWord=$RezWord. "ʝ";break;
        case  k : $RezWord=$RezWord. "к";break;
        case  l : $RezWord=$RezWord. "ɭ";break;
        case  m : $RezWord=$RezWord. "ɱ";break;
        case  n : $RezWord=$RezWord. "ŋ";break;
        case  o : $RezWord=$RezWord. "о";break;
        case  p : $RezWord=$RezWord. "р";break;
        case  q : $RezWord=$RezWord. "q";break;
        case  r : $RezWord=$RezWord. "ɾ";break;
        case  s : $RezWord=$RezWord. "ʂ";break;
        case  t : $RezWord=$RezWord. "ʈ";break;
        case  u : $RezWord=$RezWord. "ʋ";break;
        case  v : $RezWord=$RezWord. "ⱱ";break;
        case  w : $RezWord=$RezWord. "ω";break;
        case  x : $RezWord=$RezWord. "х";break;
        case  y : $RezWord=$RezWord. "у";break;
        case  z : $RezWord=$RezWord. "ʐ";break;
        case  " "  : $RezWord=$RezWord. " ";break;
        case  "."  : $RezWord=$RezWord. ".";break;
        case  ","  : $RezWord=$RezWord. ",";break;
        case  "?"  : $RezWord=$RezWord. "?";break;
        case  "!"  : $RezWord=$RezWord. "!";break;
        default : echo"*";break;
       }
     $i++;
    }
}

if($_POST['empty'])
{
$RezWord = "";
}
?>
<p/>

 <form action="" method="post">
<textarea rows="10" cols="100" name="Word"><?=$RezWord ?></textarea>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit"value="Convert">
<input type="submit" name="empty" value="Erase">
</form>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.